# Why is the standart icon not displayed?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, slds, icon

What am I doing wrong? How do I display the icon?

```
<lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="standart:work_type" alternative-text="Work Types"></lightning-icon>
        </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its **standard** not **standart**

```
<lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:work_type" alternative-text="Work Types"> 
        </lightning-icon>
        </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```